# Pass parameter in the Landing page URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm a new user of **Salesforce**.  I'm creating a landing page, and i want to pass parameter such as **User name** in the **URL** of the landing page.

I tried this:

```
mypage.com/wsmetxah3zh?&name=%%=v(@Firstname)=%%&email=%%=v(@emailaddr)=%%
```

and when i display the parameters in the landing page, for exemple :

```
<p>%%=v(name)=%%</p>
```

it doesn't work. If any one can help me i will appreciate this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [ConCat](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#concat) AmpScript function to add the parameter in the landing page.

```
%%[ 
     SET @Firstname = "Johan" 
     SET @emailaddr = "Johan@test.com" 
     SET @URL = ConCat('http://mypage.com/wsmetxah3zh?&name=',@Firstname,'&email=',@emailaddr) 
 ]%%
 <a href="%%=v(@URL)=%%">LandingPageURL!</a>
```

Also, use [QueryParameter](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#QueryParameter) function to Retrieves the value from a query string based on the key defined for it.

```
 %%[ 
     SET @Name = QueryParameter("name")
  ]%% 

  FirstName = %%=V(@Name)=%%
```